# PHPExcel setReadFilter is not filtering excel records

Tags: php

i am using PHPExcel. There are 100 rows in my excel. but i want to read only 50 records. so i set following filter. 
When i display `getHighestRow();` it says 100 rows though i have set filter for 50 row...

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
            private $z;
            public function __construct($z){
                $this->z=$z;
            }
            public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName='') {
                    if ($row > (($this->z - 1) * 1000) && $row <= ($this->z * 1000)) {
                        //echo "this- > z". $this->z;
                        return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }
        }

            $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_sqlite3;
        if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod)) 
                {
                die($cacheMethod . " caching method is not available" . EOL);
                }
            $cacheSettings = array( 
                'cacheTime' => 6000
            );              
        PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
            $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
            $objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter(50) );
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $no_of_rows=$objSheet->getHighestRow();
            echo "no_of_rows=$no_of_rows";
```

Comment: `getHighestRow` always return highest row number in the current worksheet. Reader filters doesn't affect on it. Simply read the needed data and don't worrying about `getHighestRow`.

Comment: @hindmost : do you recommend any other phpexcel reader as this method PHPExcel is leaking memory so i am struggling to split the variables as shown in above sample

Comment: I would suggest you to use `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify` to auto identify file format

Comment: you mean file format ? its already an excel. what is the benefit of it ?

Comment: The benefit is that you don't need care about appropriate reader class choice. `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify` will do it for you.

Comment: @hindmost : Thanks. Also , could you please let me know how clear $objPHPExcel variable's memory at the end of the process in above example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48154/discussion-between-logan-and-hindmost)